# Trying to figure out how to loop while grouping

Tags: php

Here is the data I have:

```
ID | Name | Family
 1 | John | Doe
 2 | Jane | Doe
 3 | John | Man
 4 | Jane | Blah
```

Basically what I am trying to do is group them by Family. I am getting the data inside a while statement and I just tried using array and array_push but that doesn't work at all.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this?

I am going to ouput this data for jquery for creating optgroups which would be grouped by Family. Currently here is what is happening:

```
while ($orders_status = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_status_query)) {
    $status_id = $orders_status['orders_status_id'];
    $status_name = $orders_status['orders_status_name'];
    $status_group = $orders_status['orders_status_group'];
}
```

That's the basic code. I tried doing this to the above mentioned code:

```
while ($orders_status = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_status_query)) {
    $status_id = $orders_status['orders_status_id'];
    $status_name = $orders_status['orders_status_name'];
    $status_group = $orders_status['orders_status_group'];

    echo 'if (currentOption.val() == "' . $status_id . '") {
              var optgroup = $("<optgroup/>");
              optgroup.attr("label", "' . $status_group . '");
              currentOption.wrapAll(optgroup);
          }
    ';
 }
```

What that did is basically created multiple Family of Doe. Instead I would like to somehow create only one Family of Doe and push Name and ID into it

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what it is you're trying to accomplish. What you've provided so far is almost useless as a question

Comment: Why haven't you posted the code you tried?

Comment: Sorry my apologies. I will update the question in a minute..

Comment: Yeah, it might help to give us what you're expecting to happen, too. An associative array with `Family` as the key?

Comment: The code is posted now. Anyone want to help me out?

Comment: This makes no sense. Explain to us what you're trying to accomplish. Examples work wonders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $family = $row["family"];
  if (empty($groups[$family])) $groups[$family] = array();
  $groups[$family] []= $row;
}

// $groups["Doe"] will have the two relevant rows...
```